# SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationship - how to properly get the 'many' collection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm not sure I properly understand how to get the collection part of the one-to-many relationship.

```
class ProjectReport(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "project_reports"

    id = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    project_id = db.Column(UUID, db.ForeignKey("projects.id"), nullable=False)
    entries = db.relationship("ProducerEntry", backref="project_report", lazy="dynamic")

class ProducerEntry(Entry):
    __tablename__ = "producer_entries"
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "Entry"}

    id = db.Column(UUID, db.ForeignKey("entries.id"), primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(UUID, db.ForeignKey("projects.id"), nullable=False)
    project_report_id = db.Column(UUID, db.ForeignKey("project_reports.id"), nullable=True)
```

My problem is that I can't just access the `entries` field.

```
for entry in self.entries:
    do_something(entry)
```

This returns `NotImplementedError`

I managed to get the data via `hybrid property` but that seems a bit of an overkill since already have the relationship, also it'd get a bit complex for further logic later on.

```
@hybrid_property
def entries(self):
    return ProducerEntry.query.filter_by(project_report_id=self.id)
```

Ab additional information is that the `ProjectReport` is basically the common columns of the `Entry` and `Project` models, and the `project_report_id` is nullable, because the entries and projects are generated first and then I can generate the project reports from them. This is how I create the reports:

```
...
project_report = ProjectReport(date_order=entry.date_order, project_id=entry.project.id)
project_report.entries.append(entry)
...
```

As far as I know I don't have to add the `project_report_id` to the producer `entry` after this.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yeah, that relationship field returns a query, so I simply should have called:

```
self.entries.all()
```

Or anything else which is handling a query.